# Best implementation follow and unfollow in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Trying to implement a following and followers and feature in Django-rest, if I were to create this not using rest framework, I have an idea how this can be done. But this time I have little to no idea how this can be done.

Please:

1)  What is the best way to do something like this assuming I am working on a big project?

2)  I am majorly lost at what to do at the serializer and view section, I just know that that in the serializer part I select the following model alone

Assuming I have a profile model like this

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    following = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='followers', blank=True)
    other content…….
```

Please any help is appreciated

Comment: I know, this is answered. But look at this solution to follower/following approach ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58794639/how-to-make-follower-following-system-with-django-model/58799650#58799650)  .. Because in that case, the unfollow would be a simple delete from  table with very simple DELETE request.

Answer (score 3):

add this to your urlpatterns

```
path('follow/<int:pk>/', FollowView.as_view({'post': 'follow'})),
path('unfollow/<int:pk>/', FollowView.as_view({'post': 'unfollow'})),
```

and in your rest views

```
class FollowView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    queryset = Profile.objects

    def follow(self, request, pk):
        # your follow code
        return Response({'message': 'now you are following'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def unfollow(self, request, pk):
        # your unfollow code
        return Response({'message': 'you are no longer following him'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

To add an item to a ManyToManyField you have to use the add function. in this case it would be with an instance of Profile.

```
profile.following.add(follow_profile)  # To add a following
profile.following.remove(follow_profile)  # To remove a following
```

That said your function would look something like this.

```
def follow(self, request, pk):
    own_profile = request.user.profile_set.first()  # or your queryset to get
    following_profile = Profile.objects.get(id=pk)
    own_profile.following.add(following_profile)  # and .remove() for unfollow
    return Response({'message': 'now you are following'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```