# ManyToMany vs. Intermediary Model for Follower-Following Relationship for Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a blog application with Django Rest Framework (very original I know) and I'm trying to add a followers/following relationship between Users. Currently my UserProfile is implemented as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

User = get_user_model()

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """Model For Extending Default Django User Model"""
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, 
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                related_name='profile')
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}'

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return f'{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}'

    @property
    def posts_list(self):
        return self.user.posts.filter(author=self.user)

    @property
    def comments_list(self):
        return self.user.comments.filter(author=self.user)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    """Automatically Create A User Profile When A New User IS Registered"""

    if created:
        user_profile = UserProfile(user=instance)
        setattr(user_profile, 'username', instance.username)
        user_profile.save()
```

My goal is to create a way to link UserProfiles via a Follower/Following relationship. My first idea was to create a ManyToMany relationship like the following:

```
followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, blank=True)
```

This makes sense to me, since a UserProfile can have multiple followers and follow multiple people. If I want to serialize this model, then I can use something like the following:

```
class UserProfileDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    posts_list = SerializerMethodField(source="get_posts_list")
    followers = SerializerMethodField(source="get_followers")
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['username', 'avatar', 'bio', 'posts_list']

    def get_posts_list(self, obj):
        return PostDetailsSerializer(obj.user.posts.filter(author=obj.user.id, is_published=True), many=True, read_only=True).data

    def get_followers(self, obj):
        return FollowersSerializer(obj.user.profile.followers, many=True, read_only=True).data
```

However, on this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58794639/how-to-make-follower-following-system-with-django-model), users suggested having an intermediary model instead of using a ManyToMany field. Other online resources seem pretty split between the two approaches. Can anybody explain when one would use ManyToMany fields over intermediary models and vice versa?

Comment: Both approaches are the same, ManyToMany relationship requires an intermediate table to save `user_id` and `following_user_id`

Comment: You will get the same thing as the other post just with `followers = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="following")`

Comment: You will need an intermediary model if you want additional information about the relationship, for example if you want to know when the relationship has started by adding a `created_on` field in the intermediary model

Comment: Got it, that makes sense.