# Django sequentially link tables through ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-related-manager

I have a User Following Django Models system based on one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58794639/how-to-make-follower-following-system-with-django-model).

How can I get all Post objects of that a user follows, having two models: Post and UserFollowings pointing at User model via ForeignKey but User model not pointing back?
I need QuerySet of Posts objects to later call serializer that I have added Posts model

Models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "author": self.user.first_name +" " + self.user.last_name
        }



class UserFollowing(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                    related_name ='following', null=True)
    following_user_id = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                    related_name='followers', null=True)
```

I have tried using `select_related` but I think it cannot work with those models.
Basically, I am looking for something like this:

```
u = User.object.get(id=num)
followers = u.followers 
followers_posts = followers.posts.all()
```

Last line returns: `'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'posts'`

Comment: I think what you want is `Post.objects.filter(user__in=u.followers.all())`

Comment: `Post.objects.filter(user__followering_following_user_id=u)`

Comment: thank you for your replies, but @sudden_appearance suggestion returns `ValueError Cannot use QuerySet for "UserFollowing": Use a QuerySet for "User"` and Willem Van Onsem code returned `FieldError Related Field got invalid lookup: followering_following_user_id` (after i changed the `followering` typo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return all posts that a user follows

```
user_instance = User.objects.only('id').get(pk=num)

following_users = UserFollowing.objects.filter(
    user_id=user_instance
).values('following_user_id')

posts = Posts.objects.filter(user__in=following_users)
```

Comment: Thank you that does it! Can you please explain why do you get `user_instance` the way you did instead of just `User.objects.get(id=num)` ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: By this way it will only return id of user instead of all data and also I think it is faster.