# How to Get all (user followings posts) in django rest framework views

Tags: filter, django-rest-framework

relative to this answer: [How to make follower-following system with django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58794639/how-to-make-follower-following-system-with-django-model/58799650#58799650)
I will like to know how to get all the post of the user that I'm following just in case I'll want to add that extra functionality in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have an another Model `Post` associated with `User`.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", related_name="posts")
```

Getting all posts of `following_user_id`, you can achieve by below query

```
following_user_ids = request.user.followers.all().values_list("following_user_id", flat=True)
posts = Post.objects.filter(user__in=following_user_ids)
```

`request.user`  is the logged-in user, `related_name="followers"` is used get all associated records from `UserFollowing` Model. `values_list()` will return the `following_user_id` in list form than pass the returned list in `Post`